# Wordpress clone in subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to make a clone of a Wordpress site into a subdirectory. So, I will have two installations, one in the root of the domain, and one in /test. My problem is that, even though I have changed the values for siteurl and home uri in database, my links will redirect to root. So, a page like domain.com/test/contact will redirect to domain.com/contact, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to follow these steps to clone your WordPress website from production to staging server -

```
1. First export database of production server WordPress website and open SQL file in an text editor.
2. Then find your domain name(domain.com) and replace it at all places with your domain name/test like domain.com/test.
3. Import production SQL file to test database from phpmyadmin.
4. Open staging WordPress admin like domain.com/test/wp-admin and go to Settings > Permalink section. Just click on the Save button to update htaccess file.
5. Optionally you can go to setting at admin page and save all general settings, menus and check Widgets area too.
6. Now you can access your domain.com/test WordPress website.
```

Comment: These are exactly the steps I followed, and I can access wp-admin and the homepage, but everything else still goes to the root pages.

Comment: you can go to setting at admin page and save all general settings,menus and permalinks.then check your /test website.

Comment: Ah, got it. I went through the permalinks, and I had to manually create an .htaccess inside the /test directory, because wordpress could not create it by itself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: if this post helped you then you can accept this answer. so this post will become helpful for newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is because your htaccess settings rewriterules. 
Take a look to it or post it here.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Ok, reading the previous answer by @anilmp40 i understand you didn't have the htaccess. I'm happy to see you solved!

Answer (score 1):

Good answer, [anil-meena](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20903214/4733266) 
However these 5 steps can be done automatically with the wordpress plugin 
[WP Staging](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-staging/). I developed this plugin because the manual process of creating a clone site for testing takes too much time and is too complicated for the regular users.
So i hope it is useful for you.